# Embedded google map with pins that link to web pages

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to implement a google map into my webpage, with pins that link to different websites. How would i go about doing this?
This my source code for the map so far:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
      ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4, "google.com"],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        url: locations[i][3],

      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a great example: https://gist.github.com/parth1020/4481893

If you want to add links then just add url to the array and in the for loop add url option.

Code:

```
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4, 'http://link.com/example1'],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5, 'http://link.com/example2']
];


for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    url: locations[i][4],

  });
```

Comment: I still can't get the url to work when i click on the marker. See the edited post above.

Comment: Add http or https to the end like mine and set url to locations[i][4]

Comment: I have no idea what i'm doing wrong, but the url still doesn't work. Is this not correct? When i comment the code the http goes away but the link is "http://google.com". Code: var locations = [
      ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4, "http://google.com"],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]